# Threading simple calculations

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I've been trying to parallelize the following function but cannot figure out how to.

```
public static Cell GetClosestCell (Cell cell)
{
    // The four calls below should be run in parallel.
    Cell temp1 = new FindNorth(cell);
    Cell temp2 = new FindSouth(cell);
    Cell temp3 = new FindWest(cell);
    Cell temp4 = new FindEast(cell);

    // Return smallest cell based on [X].
    if ((temp1.X < temp2.X) && (temp1.X < temp3.X) && (temp1.X < temp4.X))
    {
        return (temp1);
    }
    else if ((temp2.X < temp3.X) && (temp2.X < temp4.X))
    {
        return (temp2);
    }
    else if (temp3.X < temp4.X)
    {
        return (temp3);
    }
    else
    {
        return (temp4);
    }
}
```

Each of the four function calls should run in parallel but without having to initiate a thread. In other words, there should be 4 threads already running waiting for input to which I can dispatch each call.

I'm used to the normal paradigm of parallel loops and not sure how to approach this (at least not in a clean way).

Comment: You say that FindXxx takes little time. If that is the case there is no way to parallelize the 4 steps: The overhead will always dominate to useful work. Parallelize at a higher level.

Comment: I can't do that. Anything higher than this function is sequential and depends upon the previous iteration. Isn't there a way to keep 4 threads running and polling data from a queue to process as soon as it becomes available?

Comment: Sure there is but taking from that queue will oftentimes result in waiting for the next item (which often requires either spinning or OS synchronization (expensive)). How fast are your FindXxx methods (how many calls per second per core)? If they are too fast there is nothing you can do.; Extreme example: How would you parallelize two integer additions? Not possible.

Comment: I would say about 400 to 600 milliseconds for each call. The GetClosestCell function itself gets called millions of times so it really adds up.

Comment: 400ms? That is easy to parallelize. Just use the task-based solution from the existing answer. That will use the thread-pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {

        Task<Cell> task1 = new Task<Cell>(n => FindNorth((Cell)n), cell);

        Task<Cell> task2 = new Task<Cell>(n => FindSouth((Cell)n), cell);
        Task<Cell> task3 = new Task<Cell>(n => FindSouth((Cell)n), cell);
        Task<Cell> task4 = new Task<Cell>(n => FindEast((Cell)n), cell);



        task1.Start();
        task2.Start();
        task3.Start();
        task4.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Main method complete. Press <enter> to finish.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: +1, but I'd use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` in .NET 4.0 and `Task.Run()` in .NET 4.5 to create and start the `Task` in a single operation. I'd also add `Task.WaitAll()` at the end. And a closure is enough to pass the `cell` parameter, no need to make it explicit.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't this create 4 threads each time the code runs? What I want is to launch 4 threads upon program start which *wait* to process the cell. Actually the code within each FindXXXX function takes so little time that launching a new thread on each call will defeat the purpose of threading.

Comment: @Raheel: No, the default scheduler for tasks uses a thread pool, which means the threads are already running; they just receive work to do. There is still some overhead, and if the amount of work you're doing is small enough, it may not be worth dividing up the work to such small pieces. Instead, if you have a bunch of  `GetClosestCell` operations to perform, do them with `Parallel.ForEach(cells, cell => GetClosestCell(cell))`.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek: Thanks. That's the catch though. GetClosestCell has a circular dependency on itself so can only be called with the output of the previous call. I'll try your suggestions to see if actually does make a difference though.